# Bootstrap 3 navbar alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build a WordPress theme. I've got a header, main content, right sidebar and footer (so it's pretty simple, I guess).

I'm having the following problem. I'm trying to align the "navbar-brand" to it starts on the same point with my content. The following image explains it better. I want "The website" to start where my white background (post content) starts.

[image]

Any idea on how to achieve this? I'd like this to start from that point on each supported screen-size.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">TheWebsite</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INSPIRATION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CODE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FREE STUFF</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">OTHER <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Just type and hit return to search...">
                    </div>
                </form>                 
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Comment: set `margin: 0 auto` for the navbar element

Comment: Doesn't work. Already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a container div inside your navbar. Just Wrap the insides of navbar to a .container div and that should do it.

Like:

```
<div role="navigation" class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- .navbar content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a container-fluid inside my nav. I'm purely using the example posted on the bootstrap website. I've updated the original post with the code.

Comment: Change the .container-fluid class to .container. Container-fluid doesn't have defined width so it's always 100%, whereas Container has the width always defined.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's impossible to know what you've done, but it looks like you're missing a container from your Navbar code. I suggest taking a look at the documentation here:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

And also, you can view the source of this page here:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

It will show you that the second element in the Navbar HTML needs to have a `container` class applied to it to get the Navbar items to align properly.